# Resaltado de sintaxis

Tags: jquery, visual-studio

Estoy trabajando con `jquery` en `visual studio 2019`, pero sin embargo todo el código me aparece en blanco. ¿Faltará alguna extension?

[image: Codigo de ejemplo]

Comment: No es que el código "esté en blanco", sino que le falta el resaltado de sintaxis.

Comment: visual studio, o visual studio code?

Answer (score 0):

Fuente: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/reference/how-to-change-fonts-and-colors-in-the-editor?view=vs-2022

Puede cambiar la fuente predeterminada, ajustar el tamaño de fuente y cambiar los colores de primer plano y de fondo de diverso texto de Mostrar los elementos en el editor de código. Al cambiar la configuración de fuente, tenga en cuenta la información siguiente:

La configuración de Fuente y Tamaño es global para todos los elementos de texto de todos los editores de Visual Studio.

Los nombres de las fuentes con ancho fijo se enumeran en negrita.

Las opciones Primer plano del elemento, Fondo del elemento y Negrita pueden establecerse para cada tipo de elemento de texto. Por ejemplo, si cambia los colores y selecciona Negrita para Comentario y Marcadores, otros tipos de elementos de texto no se verán afectados.

Importante

Para obtener información sobre cómo personalizar las fuentes y los colores del entorno de desarrollo integrado y no solo del editor de código, consulte la página Cómo: Cambiar fuentes y colores en Visual Studio .

Cambiar la fuente predeterminada, el tamaño y los colores
Seleccione Opciones en el menú Herramientas. En Entorno, seleccione Fuentes y colores.

En Mostrar configuración para, seleccione Editor de texto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Captura de pantalla del cuadro de diálogo Opciones para cambiar fuentes y colores en el editor

Modifique las opciones Fuente y Tamaño para cambiar el nombre de fuente y el tamaño de todos los elementos de texto en todos los editores.

Seleccione el elemento apropiado en Mostrar elementos y, después, modifique las opciones Primer plano del elemento y Fondo del elemento.

Sugerencia

Haga clic en Usar predeterminadas para restablecer las opciones predeterminadas.

Seleccione Aceptar.

**Si tu tu pregunta hace referencia explícita sobre el**

> resaltado de la sintaxis

**te dejo referencia para ello** [Tutorial:Resaltado de Texto en Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/extensibility/walkthrough-highlighting-text?view=vs-2022)

Comment: interesante.. pero creo que la pregunta se referia al resaltado de sintaxis...